# Cell array usage in parfor loop (MATLAB) for matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, parfor

I have a variable `train_set` and a cell array, `R = cell(1,K)` with `K = 1000;`
So I want to do something like this

```
new_array = cell(1,K);
parfor j = 1:K
    new_array{j} = train_set * R{j};
end
```

But the thing is the variable `R` is considered a broadcast variable and therefore the entire array is loaded into each worker, instead of each `R{j}`. Of course, I can do something like making a new variable `R_new` where `R_new(:,:,j) = R{j}` but I'm afraid that would consume too much memory. Is there anything I can do to make `R{j}` sliced variable? Thank you very much :)

Comment: What makes you think that `R` is being treated as a broadcast variable?

Comment: @Suever: The compiler tells me so :(

Comment: In this case, `R` should definitely be sliced. Do you have any other references to `R` in the body of your `parfor` loop?

Comment: Did you try `array_slice( R, j, 2 )`